# D3.js with Observable, problem with event handler

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseclick-event, observablehq

I don't understand why my click event handler doesn't work. I know the event handler is running because I can see output for the three console.log() statements. The trouble is that the click event does not change the fill color. My code is all contained in one Observable notebook cell. I am using d3 version 7.3.0.

```
chart = {

  const height = 200;
  
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  let my_circles = svg
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => d * 50)
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .attr("r", d => Math.random() * 20)
      .attr("fill", "blue");

  my_circles
    .on("click", (event, d) => {
          console.log(event);
          console.log(d);
          console.log(d3.select(this));
          d3.select(this).attr("fill", "orange");
      });

  return svg.node();
}
```

Help is appeciated and thank you.

Paul

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `this` to refer something. What's the output of that third console.log say?

Comment: This is the output. I don't know how to interpret it.  ```qn {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}
_groups: Array(1)
0: [svg]
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
at: ƒ at()
concat: ƒ concat()
constructor: ƒ Array()
copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()
entries: ƒ entries()
every: ƒ every()
fill: ƒ fill()
filter: ƒ filter()
find: ƒ find()
findIndex: ƒ findIndex()
findLast: ƒ findLast()
findLastIndex: ƒ findLastIndex()
flat: ƒ flat()
flatMap: ƒ flatMap()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
includes: ƒ includes()
indexOf: ƒ indexOf()
join: ƒ join()
keys: ƒ keys()
lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()
```

Comment: arrow functions do not create *this*; you might replace it with function (event, d) {…}, or use event.target: d3.select(event.target).attr("fill", "orange");

Comment: Thank you! I tried both of those things. It works if I keep the arrow function and change "this" to "event.target". If I change it to a regular function it works with "this" or "event.target".